# How to write a recursive function which performs tasks asynchronously?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, recursion, async-await, python-asyncio

How to create a recursive coroutine function in python?

```
import asyncio

def fetch_url(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return map(fetch_url, x)
    else:
        return parsed_url(x)
```

That is when `double(10)` is called the function will be executed synchronously and whilst when `double([2,3,4])` is called it would execute asynchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "would execute asynchronously" you mean "in parallel", try this:

```
async def fetch_url(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return await asyncio.gather(*[fetch_url(url) for url in x])

    return parsed_url(x)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a function normal function which internally is able to call itself asynchronously? That is, in the above code, `fetch_url` is a coroutine and has to be executed inside a loop even if a single url needs fetching. Is there a way to make this function always callable but internally async and ideally recursive?

Comment: `fetch_url(url)` means it is a couroutine.  Instead of asyncio, you might want to consider `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: Is there a way to use `concurrent.futures` to perform asynchronous tasks in a single thread? AFAIK `concurrent.futures` requires the use of multithreading (`ThreadPoolExecutor`) or multiprocessing (`ProcessPoolExecutor`)?